# Remove spaces with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the space between two words with a regex, however this does not seem to work.

```
$pattern = "#\<a href=\"(.+?) (.+?)\">#is";
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, "\<a href=\"\\1%20\\2\">", $txt);
```

I also need this to work for multiple words, but only withing the  tags, as the rest of the text should have spaces. So a str_replace won't work (I think?)

Any tips?

Comment: You're right. `str_replace()` is not a fit for this situation.

Comment: Doesn't the browser encode URLs for you?

Answer (score 1):

The stable solution would be: Use DOM to retrieve the href value, use `str_replace()` to remove the spaces and then write back the value using DOM again.

Don't use regexes to handle html / xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex code to remove white spaces

\s+(?=[^()]*\

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regex:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~(?:href="|(?<!^)\G)\K([^" ]*)\s+~g', "$1%20", $txt);
```

`\G` matches at the end of the previous match so that you can replace multiple spaces in a single attribute.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jF6tV6).

Comment: For some reason this is just crashing my script. Should this be with the other 2 or in a seprate function?

Comment: @Coolcrab Could it be that you have a huge file to process? Regex is bad at processing large pages; you might want to process a few lines at time. And what do you mean by 'should this be with the other 2'?